# ics file not reflected in outlook calendar

Tags: php, outlook, phpmailer, icalendar

I am trying to send an meeting invite from a php code, I am sending the meeting invite through an ics file. However the ics file is coming in as attachment in Gmail but not being reflected in Ms Outlook.

This is the following File Format that I have:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 10.0 MIMEDIR//EN
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:REQUEST
X-MS-OLK-FORCEINSPECTOROPEN:TRUE
BEGIN:VEVENT
ATTENDEE;CN=mail@veershubhranshu.com;RSVP=TRUE:mailto:mail@veershubhranshu.com
ATTENDEE;CN=srivastav.veer@gmail.com;RSVP=TRUE:mailto:srivastav.veer@gmail.com
ATTENDEE;CN=veer@veershubhranshu.com;RSVP=TRUE:mailto:veer@veershubhranshu.com
CLASS:PUBLIC
CREATED:20140626T005704Z
DESCRIPTION:When: Thursday\, June 26\, 2014 10:00 AM-10:30 AM (UTC-08:00) P
    acific Time (US & Canada).\nWhere: Nowhere\n\nNote: The GMT offset above d
    oes not reflect daylight saving time adjustments.\n\n*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*\n
    \nsdcsdascsdcs\n
DTEND:20140626T173000Z
DTSTAMP:20140626T005704Z
DTSTART:20140626T170000Z
LAST-MODIFIED:20140626T005704Z
LOCATION:Nowhere
ORGANIZER;CN="Veer Shubhranshu Shrivastav":mailto:mail.@veershubhranshu.com
PRIORITY:5
SEQUENCE:0
SUMMARY;LANGUAGE=en-us:Test Meeting
TRANSP:OPAQUE
UID:040000008200E00074C5B7101A82E00800000000E02849DF9E90CF01000000000000000
    010000000D1CC646A48A62440A0D2308D1F4960AA
X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2//E
    N">\n<HTML>\n<HEAD>\n<META NAME="Generator" CONTENT="MS Exchange Server ve
    rsion 08.00.0681.000">\n<TITLE></TITLE>\n</HEAD>\n<BODY>\n<!-- Converted f
    rom text/rtf format -->\n\n<P DIR=LTR><SPAN LANG="en-us"><FONT FACE="Calib
    ri">When: Thursday\, June 26\, 2014 10:00 AM-10:30 AM (UTC-08:00) Pacific 
    Time (US &amp\; Canada).</FONT></SPAN></P>\n\n<P DIR=LTR><SPAN LANG="en-us
    "><FONT FACE="Calibri">Where: Nowhere</FONT></SPAN></P>\n\n<P DIR=LTR><SPA
    N LANG="en-us"><FONT FACE="Calibri">Note: The GMT offset above does not re
    flect daylight saving time adjustments.</FONT></SPAN></P>\n\n<P DIR=LTR><S
    PAN LANG="en-us"><FONT FACE="Calibri">*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*</FONT></SPAN></P
    >\n\n<P DIR=LTR><SPAN LANG="en-us"><FONT FACE="Calibri">sdcsdascsdcs</FONT
    ></SPAN><SPAN LANG="en-us"></SPAN></P>\n\n</BODY>\n</HTML>
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:TENTATIVE
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-IMPORTANCE:1
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-INTENDEDSTATUS:BUSY
X-MICROSOFT-DISALLOW-COUNTER:FALSE
X-MS-OLK-ALLOWEXTERNCHECK:TRUE
X-MS-OLK-AUTOSTARTCHECK:FALSE
X-MS-OLK-CONFTYPE:0
X-MS-OLK-SENDER;CN="Veer Shubhranshu Shrivastav":mailto:mail@veershubhranshu.com
BEGIN:VALARM
TRIGGER:-PT15M
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:Reminder
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

I am not able to figure out where is the problem. This is my Php code

```
<?php
$domain = 'xyz.com';

//Create Email Headers
$mime_boundary = "----Meeting Booking----".MD5(TIME());

$headers = "From: ".$from_name." <".$from_address.">\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ".$from_name." <".$from_address.">\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"$mime_boundary\"\n";
$headers .= "Content-class: urn:content-classes:calendarmessage\n";

//Create Email Body (HTML)
$message = "--$mime_boundary\r\n";
$message .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\n";
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n\n";
$message .= "<html>\n";
$message .= "<body>\n";
$message .= '<p>Dear '.$to_name.',</p>';
$message .= '<p>'.$description.'</p>';
$message .= "</body>\n";
$message .= "</html>\n";
$message .= "--$mime_boundary\r\n";

$ical =
'BEGIN:VCALENDAR' . "\r\n" .
'PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 10.0 MIMEDIR//EN' . "\r\n" .
'VERSION:2.0' . "\r\n" .
'METHOD:REQUEST' . "\r\n" .
'X-MS-OLK-FORCEINSPECTOROPEN:TRUE'."\r\n".
'BEGIN:VEVENT'."\r\n".
'ATTENDEE;CN=mail@veershubhranshu.com;RSVP=TRUE:mailto:mail@veershubhranshu.com'."\r\n".
'ATTENDEE;CN=srivastav.veer@gmail.com;RSVP=TRUE:mailto:srivastav.veer@gmail.com'."\r\n".
'ATTENDEE;CN=veer@veershubhranshu.com;RSVP=TRUE:mailto:veer@veershubhranshu.com'."\r\n".
'CLASS:PUBLIC'."\r\n".
'CREATED:20140626T005704Z'."\r\n".
'DESCRIPTION:When: Thursday\, June 26\, 2014 10:00 AM-10:30 AM (UTC-08:00) P
acific Time (US & Canada).\nWhere: Nowhere\n\nNote: The GMT offset above d
oes not reflect daylight saving time adjustments.\n\n*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*\n
\nsdcsdascsdcs\n'."\r\n".
'DTEND:20140626T173000Z'."\r\n".
'DTSTAMP:20140626T005704Z'."\r\n".
'DTSTART:20140626T170000Z'."\r\n".
'LAST-MODIFIED:20140626T005704Z'."\r\n".
'LOCATION:Nowhere'."\r\n".
'ORGANIZER;CN="Veer Shubhranshu Shrivastav":mailto:mail.@veershubhranshu.com'."\r\n".
'PRIORITY:5'."\r\n".
'SEQUENCE:0'."\r\n".
'SUMMARY;LANGUAGE=en-us:Test Meeting'."\r\n".
'TRANSP:OPAQUE'."\r\n".
'UID:040000008200E00074C5B7101A82E00800000000E02849DF9E90CF01000000000000000
010000000D1CC646A48A62440A0D2308D1F4960AA'."\r\n".
'X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2//E
N">\n<HTML>\n<HEAD>\n<META NAME="Generator" CONTENT="MS Exchange Server ve
rsion 08.00.0681.000">\n<TITLE></TITLE>\n</HEAD>\n<BODY>\n<!-- Converted f
rom text/rtf format -->\n\n<P DIR=LTR><SPAN LANG="en-us"><FONT FACE="Calib
ri">When: Thursday\, June 26\, 2014 10:00 AM-10:30 AM (UTC-08:00) Pacific 
Time (US &amp\; Canada).</FONT></SPAN></P>\n\n<P DIR=LTR><SPAN LANG="en-us
"><FONT FACE="Calibri">Where: Nowhere</FONT></SPAN></P>\n\n<P DIR=LTR><SPA
N LANG="en-us"><FONT FACE="Calibri">Note: The GMT offset above does not re
flect daylight saving time adjustments.</FONT></SPAN></P>\n\n<P DIR=LTR><S
PAN LANG="en-us"><FONT FACE="Calibri">*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*</FONT></SPAN></P
>\n\n<P DIR=LTR><SPAN LANG="en-us"><FONT FACE="Calibri">sdcsdascsdcs</FONT
></SPAN><SPAN LANG="en-us"></SPAN></P>\n\n</BODY>\n</HTML>'."\r\n".
'X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:TENTATIVE'."\r\n".
'X-MICROSOFT-CDO-IMPORTANCE:1'."\r\n".
'X-MICROSOFT-CDO-INTENDEDSTATUS:BUSY'."\r\n".
'X-MICROSOFT-DISALLOW-COUNTER:FALSE'."\r\n".
'X-MS-OLK-ALLOWEXTERNCHECK:TRUE'."\r\n".
'X-MS-OLK-AUTOSTARTCHECK:FALSE'."\r\n".
'X-MS-OLK-CONFTYPE:0'."\r\n".
'X-MS-OLK-SENDER;CN="Veer Shubhranshu Shrivastav":mailto:mail@veershubhranshu.com'."\r\n".
'BEGIN:VALARM'."\r\n".
'TRIGGER:-PT15M'."\r\n".
'ACTION:DISPLAY'."\r\n".
'DESCRIPTION:Reminder'."\r\n".
'END:VALARM'."\r\n".
'END:VEVENT'."\r\n".
'END:VCALENDAR'."\r\n";
$message .= 'Content-Type: text/calendar;name="veer-invite.ics";method=REQUEST\n';
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n\n";
$message .= $ical;

$mailsent = mail($to_address, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's some great investigation of this problem in [this open issue in PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues/175). Though it's not a problem of PHPMailer's making (it's Outlook's fault), there's no easy way to build the workaround in PHPMailer - you may be better off usig a different system to build your MIME structure, such as [Zend_MIME](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.mime.html).

Answer (score 0):

Outlook requires that the text/calendar part must be the one and only MIME part.

HTML body can be set as part of VCALENDAR.

Comment: What I did was I sent a mail invite from outlook, downloaded the ics file, read the contents but there was not MIME part there..

Comment: Download ICS file from where? Outlook does not send ICS files. Do you have access to the whole MIME message?

Comment: Look I'll tell you.. I am sending a meeting invite using the above PHP code, I am getting an ICS file in GMAIL and WebMail, but it is not reflected in Outlook. That is, I am not getting an attachment in the Outlook. And even I don't receive the meeting invitation on the Outlook as I get in Gmail or Webmail

Comment: This is not quite true. Outlook expects the vcal part to be an additional part of the multipart/alternative structure, though it may also work if it's not part of a multipart structure.

Comment: What problem exactly are you trying to solve? That your message does not look like a meeting invitation/update in Outlook?